# Does the Krasovskii Regularization Preserve Measurability?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, control-theory

The Krasovskii regularization for the flow map (set-valued) $F$ over the flow set $C$ is defined as
$$\hat{F}(x)\triangleq\bigcap_{\delta >0}\overline{\text{co}}F((x+\delta\mathbb{B})\cap C),\quad\forall x\in \overline{C}.$$

Now, is it true that if $F$ is Lebesgue measurable, then so is $\hat{F}$?

Comment: I attempted to ask this question before Christmas but what I posted was a little ambiguous. Hopefully this more straight to the point.

Comment: Does $\overline{\operatorname{con}}$ stand for the closure of the convex hull? if so, your set is the intersection of closed sets and hence closed. If the topological space is a Polish space, then the regularization you are describing in your posting is then measurable (Borel measurable in fact).

Comment: @OliverDíaz , yes, that is the closure of the convex hull. Thank you for your comment, I will think about what you have said.

Comment: If your underlying space is Euclidean ($\mathbb{R}^n$, for some $n$) then no need to talk about Polish spaces. You regularization is a Borel set. The issue is when your Linear space is a product of linear spaces that are not separable for then not every open set (in the product) is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra. I suspect you are not dealing with the later so, yes, your regularization is in fact a Borel set.

Comment: @OliverDíaz, yes, my space is Euclidean.

Comment: You do not need the flow set in the statement of the problem. It just complicates the definition of the problem without adding anything to it. Also, $\hat F$ is now a set valued-map. How do you define measurability then?

Comment: @KBS, this is another point of confusion for me since it is set-valued. The flow set is necessary in the definition I am working with, given that this part of a much great problem I am working on.

Comment: Remove the flow from this problem. It is more confusing than anything else because you do not give the context (no definition of a flow map nor a flow set) and it does not change anything. Your question needs to be minimal in this regard.

Comment: @KBS Thanks for the critique, I'll redo the question.